# add 'ids' to checkbox elems from ~ sibling element innerText val

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, foreach, css-selectors

**Goal:** I am trying to iterate through a series of checkboxes, and add an "id" to each elem with the value of the checkboxes sibling text value. *i.e.* inner text of `.k-in`

Recent attempt:

```
function addSelectors() {
    const checks = document.querySelectorAll('.k-treeview-lines input[type="checkbox"]');

    [].forEach.call(checks, function (checks) {
        let knn = document.querySelectorAll('.k-treeview-lines input[type="checkbox"] ~ .k-in');
        checks.id = knn.innerText;
    });
}
```

HTML is a series of the below:

```
<div class="k-mid">
  <span class="k-checkbox-wrapper" role="presentation">
    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" id="undefined"
           class="k-checkbox"><-- id here
    <span class="k-checkbox-label checkbox-span"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="k-in">I want this</span><---- this text
</div>
```

*Do not want to load jQuery...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    function addSelectors() {
        const checks = document.querySelectorAll(
            '.k-treeview-lines input[type="checkbox"]'
        );
        checks.forEach(function (checkbox) {
            const textVal = checkbox.parentElement.nextElementSibling.innerText;
            checkbox.setAttribute("id", textVal);
        });
    }
    addSelectors();
```

```html
<div class="k-treeview-lines">
    <div class="k-mid">
        <span class="k-checkbox-wrapper" role="presentation">
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                tabindex="-1"
                id="undefined"
                class="k-checkbox"
            />
            <span class="k-checkbox-label checkbox-span"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="k-in">tempID</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The item you are requesting is not actually the sibling, they don't share the same parent.

You could do something like this:

```js
        function addSelectors() {
            const checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
        
            checks.forEach(c => {
                 c.id = c.parentNode.nextElementSibling.innerText;
            });
        }
        addSelectors();
```

```html
<div class="k-mid">
<span class="k-checkbox-wrapper" role="presentation">
<input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" id="undefined" class="k-checkbox">
<span class="k-checkbox-label checkbox-span"></span>
</span>
<span class="k-in">I want this</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Dang, yeah just caught that myself. Sorry for the mishap! What selector could I attempt at now... :/

Comment: Thanks! oh perhaps I will need to handle for the spaces I imagine

Comment: You could adapt the id before setting it inside the `forEach`.

Comment: @docholiday please mark the answer as correct if you already solved the issue. Thanks